# Check decorator is attached to a view function

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
@permission_required()
def my_home(request):
    import functools
    from walterwhite.views import my_nav  # Replace with your view function
    if hasattr(my_nav, '__wrapped__') and isinstance(my_nav.__wrapped__, functools.partial):
        print(f'{my_nav.__name__} has the @permission_required decorator')
    else:
        print(f'{my_nav.__name__} does not have the @permission_required decorator')


    return HttpResponse('In home')


@permission_required()
def my_nav(request):
    Res='Hello this is the navigation bar' 
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Here it giving me the response as my_nav does not have @perm decorator even though it has decorator attached.
How to check whether permission_required is attached or not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator), you need to define the required permission to the `permission_required`. For example, for `polls.add_choice`:

```
@permission_required("polls.add_choice")
def my_view(request):
    ...
```